# SQL Server Management Studio doesn't connect to server

Tags: sql-server-2014

I just installed SQL Server Management Studio and it auto creates a server with your PC name to connect to, but it doesn't connect - all I get is this error. I tried reinstalling and also there's no server with that name in the services to start

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to DESKTOP-7UA72F9.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Comment: Try turning off firewall. Also, if you are trying to connect from your computer to the DB installed in the same computer, attempt to connect to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

Comment: It gives me the same error

Comment: If you've installed the **Express** edition of SQL Server, then by default you have a **named instance** `SQLEXPRESS` , and you need to connect to it using `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `DESKTOP-7UA72F9\SQLEXPRESS` as the server/instance name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've installed Management studio only. Server doesn't come with it. Could you provide additional info on what steps you went through exactly? What install files did you use? 
If you're looking to play with MS SQL Server, there is an Express version, it's free.

Comment: It is sql server management studio 2014 and then installed the 17.7 version of  SSMS

Comment: and it is the 2014 express version

Comment: Ok, you just wrote that you installed Management Studio 2014 and after that Management Studio 2017 (Management Studio = SSMS). 'Express' is not a version of SSMS but version of MS SQL Server. Did you install server itself? Or are you targeting some remote server instead of the local server?

Comment: Here is the download link for SQL Server Express: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express

Comment: I am still a student and we need to do an assignment creating and displaying tables and editing them on sql server management studio 2014 , we did not get the software and now I am actually not sure what to install to connect to a local database just to do this work

Comment: Well, if your teacher didn't give you any additional info, it's safe to presume that you can use the Express edition. Download the installer, walk yourself through the install process (there is a bunch of how-to videos and articles out there) and then use Management Studio to access the server, create databases and all the rest.